# Getting Undefined method `dump' for MultiJson:Module for jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an undefined method "dump" for MultiJson:Module

My jbuilder version is 1.5.3
multi_json version is 1.0.2

> // in create.json.jbuilder
>
> json.(current_user, :id, :email)

Answer (score 1):

Had conflict for the multi_json version required for context.io and jbuilder.

Resolved the issue, commented out context.io gem (no longer required in the application, dependent on multi_json version 1.0.2) and updated multi_json version in gemfile to '1.8.2'